# Determine all solutions of the following matrix equation system

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine all solutions of the matrix system: $$AX+X^TB+CX^T=D$$ where

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\-1&-1&1&-1\\1&-1&-1&-1\\1&0&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$, $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&-1\\-1&0&-1&0\\2&-1&1&1\\-1&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$, $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&-1\\2&3&1&0\\-1&-4&0&-1\\0&0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}$$, $$D=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&-1\\2&3&1&0\\-1&-4&0&-1\\0&0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}$$.

Hint:
$$vec(X^T)=p(m,n)vec(X)$$ for all $$X \in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$$ where $$p(m,n)=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n E_{ij}\otimes E_{ij}^T$$.

I think X must be a $$4\times 4$$ matrix, thus $$p(4,4)=E_{11}\otimes E_{11}+E_{12}\otimes E_{21}+E_{13}\otimes E_{31}+E_{14}\otimes E_{41}+E{21}\otimes E_{12}+E_{22}\otimes E_{22}+E_{23}\otimes E_{32}+E_{24}\otimes E_{42}+E_{31}\otimes E_{13}+E_{32}\otimes E_{23}+E_{41}\otimes E_{14}+E_{42}\otimes E_{24}+E_{43}\otimes E_{34}+E_{44}\otimes E_{44}$$ I know how to solve a system of the form $$AX+XB=C$$ the solution will be: $$\left(B^T\oplus A\right)vec(X)=vec(C)$$ but I do not know how to find the solution of the above system.

Comment: $X$ has to be 4 x 4 since $D$ is 4 x 4 so $AX$ has to be 4 x 4 (and for the multiplication to make sense, X has to be 4 x something, and the something has to be 4 by the size of $D$).

Comment: Yes, but how do I find the solution with the vec operator, as I expossed above for the equation $$AX+ XB=C$$ the solution will be given by: